# Reflection.Emit unsafe code

Tags: c#, .net, f#, reflection.emit

I'm doing some hacking with Reflection Emit in F#. I'm trying to do the equivalent of this C# code:

```
var ass = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("Test"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
var mb = ass.DefineDynamicModule("Test", "Test.dll", false);
var t = mb.DefineType("Foo", TypeAttributes.Public, typeof(ValueType));
t.DefineField("foo", typeof(int*), FieldAttributes.Public);
t.CreateType();
ass.Save("Test.dll");
```

The line in particular is the definefield line. In F# the closest I can get is

```ml
let f = t.DefineField("foo", (typeof<nativeptr<int>>), FieldAttributes.Public)
```

However the compiled field ends up compiled to of type IntPtr instead of int*.(Note its an IntPtr for nativeint or any other type too)

Additionally, I'd like to be able to use the struct I defined defined programatically and have a Foo* in another struct, but obviously I'm not able to use typeof in that case (in either C# or F#). Is there a way to define a field as Foo* from the Type/TypeBuilder?

Before anyone points out that this is all potentially insane (and I agree), it is for a fun project for myself to figure out how crazy I can generate code that C# mignt not let me :)

Answer (score 4):

I believe `ilsigptr<int>` is the F# counterpart to C#'s `int*`.

See also:

- [Don Syme's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2006/08/24/715635.aspx), dead link, see [archived copy](https://web.archive.org/web/20140428143353/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2006/08/24/715635.aspx)
- [`ilsigptr<'T>` on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370431.aspx), dead link, see [archived copy](https://web.archive.org/web/20140716144647/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370431.aspx)
- [F# sources on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/128f3bc8daf02fcd44724d7999252a1c8cc0e73c/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types-prelude.fs#L70)

Comment: This works great for the 1st case:
let f = t.DefineField("foo", (typeof<ilsigptr<int>>), FieldAttributes.Public)
    
Thanks!

Comment: For the 2nd case

    let p = typedefof<ilsigptr<_>>.MakeGenericType([|t :> Type|])
    let f = t.DefineField("rec", p, FieldAttributes.Public)

It throws an InvalidOperation exception on MakeGenericType as it as inferred the generic type for ilsigptr, whereas for


    let p = typedefof<Action<_>>.MakeGenericType([|t :> Type|])
    let f = t.DefineField("rec", p, FieldAttributes.Public)

Works great. I'm guessing theres something special about ilsigptr, but it would be great to get access to a pointer to a generated struct. 

Any thoughts?

Comment: Actually, It turns out you can do this, which works for all cases 
    let p = t.MakePointerType()
    let f = t.DefineField("rec", p, FieldAttributes.Public)

Whew. Thanks for the help Daniel. Marking as answer as it was a big "pointer" in the right direction.

Comment: Ah, too easy. Glad you figured it out.